# Issue with transforming a stateful widget to Bloc architecture

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, agora.io

I am trying to transform my Stateful widget to a bloc architecture,

Before, everything is working:

```
@override
void initState() {
AgoraClient _engine = AgoraClient(
      agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
          appId: Global.agoraAppId,
          channelName: channelName,
          tokenUrl: 'http://10.0.0.4:8080'),
      enabledPermission: [Permission.camera, Permission.microphone],
      agoraChannelData: AgoraChannelData(
        channelProfile: ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting,
        clientRole: role,
      ),
    );
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AgoraVideoViewer(client: _engine)
```

So I move this part to bloc and repository

**LiveVideoBloc**

```
Stream<LiveVideoState> _mapLiveVideoInitToState(event) async* {
    yield state.copyWith(status: LiveVideoStatus.loading);
    try {
      AgoraClient _engine = _liveRepository.initRtcEngine(
        channelName: event.channelName,
        role: event.role,
      );

      yield state.copyWith(
          engine: _engine, status: LiveVideoStatus.loaded);
    } catch (e) {
      yield state.copyWith(
        status: LiveVideoStatus.error,
        failure: Failure(message: 'Failed to init'),
      );
    }
  }
```

**live_repository**

```
@override
  AgoraClient initRtcEngine({
    required String channelName,
    required ClientRole role,
  }) {

    AgoraClient _engine = AgoraClient(
      agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
          appId: Global.agoraAppId,
          channelName: channelName,
          tokenUrl: 'http://10.0.0.1:8080'),
      enabledPermission: [Permission.camera, Permission.microphone],
      agoraChannelData: AgoraChannelData(
        channelProfile: ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting,
        clientRole: role,
      ),
    );

    return _engine;
  }
```

And I add the event after **BlocProvider**
During my testing the event is fired but

`return AgoraVideoViewer(client: state.engine)`

throw `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(5, request is refused, null, null)`

By checking Agora API document I believe it is because the Agora engine is not initialize.

I just start learning bloc, is there anything wrong with my architecture setup?